# Effect of static magnetic field on metal plate

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

What happens when we introduce a static magnetic field perpendicular to a metal plate? I feel that due to presence of free charges in metal plate and since it's at non-zero temperature, the free charges move randomly. Though the magnetic field is static, due to the random fluctuations of motions of electron, I feel there should be small eddy currents everywhere on the plate. Is that what happens?

Answer (score 1):

The magnet induces a magnetic field in the plate, which protrudes out the other side of the plate. For thin plates, the resulting field lines with the plate look pretty much like the original field lines without the plate.

Answer (score 0):

In a metal plate (in the absence of a field) the free electrons move randomly in straight lines.
In a static magnetic field, they move randomly along curves. There is no resultant current, and no change in the average kinetic energy. In an alternating magnetic field eddy currents can form and heat the metal.